# Sort text files with multiple lines as a row

Tags: linux, text-processing, sort

I have a text file in this format:

```
####################################
KEY2
VAL21
VAL22
VAL23
VAL24
####################################
KEY1
VAL11
VAL12
VAL13
VAL14
####################################
KEY3
VAL31
VAL32
VAL33
VAL34
```

I want sort this file by `KEY` line and keep next 4 lines with it in result so sorted result should be:

```
####################################
KEY1
VAL11
VAL12
VAL13
VAL14
####################################
KEY2
VAL21
VAL22
VAL23
VAL24
####################################
KEY3
VAL31
VAL32
VAL33
VAL34
```

is there a way to do this ?

Comment: don't [cross post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/866466/sort-text-files-and-multiple-lines-as-a-row) please

Comment: @Zanna: I think there is a exclusion for unix and askubuntu sections as these two have a lot of overlap with eachother! I think I read about this in unix's meta section

Comment: relevant meta question asked here by AU mod :) [How should questions cross-posted on Ask Ubuntu be handled?](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/990)

Comment: @RYN The problem wouldn't be the overlap, in fact a lot of SE sites overlap, but that the people giving answers might not know about the answers on the other site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`msort(1)`](http://billposer.org/Software/msort.html) was designed to be able to sort files with multi-line records.  It has an optional gui, as well as a normal and usable-for-humans command line version.  (At least, humans that like to read manuals carefully and look for examples...)

AFAICT, you can't use an arbitrary pattern for records, so unless your records are fixed-size (in bytes, not characters or lines).  `msort` does have a `-b` option for records that are blocks of lines separated by blank lines.

You can transform your input into a format that will work with `-b` pretty easily, by putting a blank line before every `###...` (except the first one).

By default, it prints statistics on stderr, so at least it's easy to tell when it didn't sort because it thought the entire input was a single record.

---

**`msort` works on your data.**  The `sed` command prepends a newline to every `#+` line except for line 1.  `-w` sorts the whole record (lexicographically).  There are options for picking what part of a record to use as a key, but I didn't need them.

I also left out stripping the extra newlines.

```
$ sed '2,$ s/^#\+/\n&/' unsorted.records | msort -b -w 2>/dev/null 
####################################
KEY1
VAL11
VAL12
VAL13
VAL14

####################################
KEY2
VAL21
VAL22
VAL23
VAL24

####################################
KEY3
VAL31
VAL32
VAL33
VAL34
```

I didn't have any luck with `-r '#'` to use that as the record separator.  It thought the whole file was one record.

Comment: thank you very much; `msort` is very useful; thanks (about `-r` it seems it is because there are more than one # i used `-d` and it worked

Comment: cool! (+1)`msort -qwr '#' ex`  works for me (well it chages the output rec. separator)

Answer (score 9):

A solution is to first change the line feeds inside a block to a unused character of your choice ('|' in the example below), to sort the result and to change back the chosen separator to the original line feed:

```
sed -e 'N; N; N; N; N; s/\n/|/g' file.txt \
| sort -k2,2 -t\| \
| sed 's/|/\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks; this works but it is very dirty specially when the data is dirty too! if the lines after the key was 100 then I need to put 100 `;N` there, and it can get difficult to find a character that is not used in text itself; it is very good for `sort` or `awk` , ... be able to do multiline sorting

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -0ne 'print sort /(#+[^#]*)/g' file.txt
```

- `perl -0`   slurps the entire file
- `/(....)/g` match and extract the records
- `print sort ...` sort and print them

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that should work with any number of lines in a `KEY` section:

```
# extract delimiter
delim=$(head -n1 <infile)
sed '/#/d;/KEY/h;G;s/\n/\x02/' infile | nl -ba -nrz -s $'\002' | sort -t $'\002' -k3 -k1,1 |
cut -d $'\002' -f2 | sed '/KEY/{x;s/.*/'"${delim}"'/;G}'
```

This works by saving the delimiter into a variable (to then remove it from the input). It then appends the `KEY*` to each line in its corresponding section using a low ascii char (which is unlikely to occur in your input) as a separator and then `n`umbers all `l`ines using the same separator. It's then only a matter of `sort`ing by the 3rd and 1st field and `cut`ting the middle column and then restoring the delimiters via a final `sed`. Do note that with the above, `KEY12` will sort before `KEY2` so adjust the `sort` command per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the POSIX Awk [stdlib library](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib):

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/awklib -f
$0 ~ "#" {x++}
{q[x] = q[x] ? q[x] RS $0 : $0}
END {
  arr_sort(q)
  for (x in q) print q[x]
}
```